# UserForm for Bill of Materials

Tags: userform

I am trying to simplify an excel worksheet that is populated by a list of Bill of materials.

Each row in the worksheet has the station (Weld, Mill, Saw) name, part number, part name. A single part number can travel to different stations, but no part can be in the same station more than once.

I am hoping to create a userform that would ask for the station and then present all the possible part numbers. After the part number would be selected the entire row would be highlighted signalling the part has been sent out.

What would be the best way to go about this problem? I am having difficulty linking the workstation to all the part numbers that could be at that workstation. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLNDW.jpg)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).